# Is capturing only audio using chrome.desktopCapture API possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome-extension,i want to use desktopCapture API to only capture the window audio.I do not want the video stream.

But it turns out the streamId would be undefined always when i am trying to use it like shown below.

```js
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['audio'],(streamId,options) => {
  //retrieve mediastream using streamId and navigator API
})
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong or what approach i should take to capture browser audio.

Comment: Sounds like a bug/limitation in Chrome. You'll probably have to use a demuxer/muxer library to extract the audio track e.g. there's ffmpeg.js and ffmpeg.wasm.

Comment: Okay, is there any other way to capture audio coming from browser? Get access to the browser audio stream?

Comment: There's [web audio](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio).

Comment: I am right now kind of doing the same thing.. but the issue arises when the user is using headphones/earphones. Then i cannot record the sound from the browser if the user is on a meeting. Also am using the navigator,mediaDevices API to get all the available audio-input devices and checking if this would have that stream.It's a hit and miss.